# With Appium how to click the "home" button or launch the home screen in ios simulator?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios, saucelabs

I am trying to launch the "home" screen in ios simulator with Appium, but failed to find any api to do that .

Any suggestions would be of great help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for responding ,seems like there is no way the home screen can be launched , even java robot keys "command+shift+home" doesn't work .

So I had to write one apple script, when called will launch the home screen in the simulator .

it's here

```
    try
    tell application "System Events"

        if exists process "Simulator" then
            tell process "Dock"
                delay 2
                set frontmost to true
                activate
                tell list 1
                    try
                        perform action "AXShowMenu" of UI element "Simulator"
                        delay 2
                        #click accssibilitytitle "Open" of menu item of menu1 -- up arrow
                        key code 126 -- up arrow

                        key code 126 -- up arrow

                        key code 126 -- up arrow
                        key code 126 -- up arrow

                        key code 126 -- up arrow
                        -- key code 125 -- down arrow                   
                        delay 2
                        key code 36 -- return key                       
                    on error errMsg
                        if errMsg contains "Simulator" then
                            log "Simulator is not present in the dock... To run the automation, add Simulator in the dock and try again!!!"

                            return
                        else
                            log errMsg

                            return
                        end if
                    end try
                end tell
            end tell
        end if


    end tell
on error errMsg
    log errMsg

end try

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Simulator"
    tell menu bar item 5 of menu bar 1
        delay 3
        click
        delay 5
        click menu item "Home" of menu 1
        delay 3
    end tell
end tell
```

It is able to successfully bring the simulator in focus by right click on the simulator icon present in dock and then selecting "Home" from the "Hardware" menu (which is menu 5) .

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation in ios.We cannot send key code to press home button in ios and because of this limitation we cannot automate home button.But in android we can do that using keycodes.In iOS automation we cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

As per link:
https://github.com/appium/java-client/releases/tag/v5.0.0-BETA6

One enhancement has been added which is:
**[ENHANCEMENT] iOS XCUIT mode automation: API to run application in background was added.**

Maybe you can try using Java-Client v5.0.0-BETA6 and try out this API

Answer (score 0):

During in test your app , you can run your app  in background an get back.

to do this you have to add

`protected IOSDriver iosDriver;`

after definition

```
@Test
@Description("Some Description")
public void testSearchZeroResultAndHomeBack(){

   // run app in background for 5 seconds
    iosDriver.runAppInBackground(5);

    Assert.assertTrue(isTextDisplayedOnPage("0 ilan"));
}
```

// run app in background for 5 seconds

```
    iosDriver.runAppInBackground(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your current appium driver you need to use following code. driver_iOS is object of appium driver:

`driver_iOS.ExecuteScript("client:client.deviceAction(\"Home\")");`

If you want you can quit this driver once your work is done i.e. `driver_iOS.Quit();`

I hope it will work for you.